# Azure CLI: Why AZ command fails locally by runs in Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

az command to list storage accounts using *--query* runs in Azure Cloud Shell but fails when run locally.

Any idea why?

I am using:

- Windows 10PC
- Python version 3.9.1
- AZ CLI: 2.23.0

Steps:

- Run PowerShell as Admin
- Login successfully with az login
- Run following commands:

Works locally (Storage / no *--query*):

```
az storage account list  --output tsv
```

Works locally (Container / with *--query*)

```
az container list --query "[?contains(name, 'mycontainer2')]" --output tsv
```

Fails locally / Works in Cloud Shell (Storage/ with *--query*):

```
az storage account list --query "[?contains(name,'terraformXX')].name" --output tsv
```

Exception:

*].name was unexpected at this time.*

C:\WINDOWS\system32>  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli storage account list --query [?contains(name,'terraformXX')].name --output tsv

The error suggests that some escape character is required. No luck finding a solution with escape characters + it works in Cloud Shell, so I think might be a misleading message.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running Azure CLI in PowerShell, there always some escape issues, when running it in Azure Cloud Shell, even if you choose `PowerShell` instead of `Bash`, it will work, as Azure Cloud Shell runs on a Linux machine `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`, mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features).

To solve the issue, finding a solution with escape characters every time is not a long-term plan, I recommend you to use [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) in Windows, just run the command in it, then will work fine.

[image]

**Besides**, if your environment is Windows, you can use [azure powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-4.8.0) directly, make sure you have [installed the `Az` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.8.0), then use the command below.

```
Connect-AzAccount
(Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object {$_.StorageAccountName -like '*test*'}).StorageAccountName
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy. Very helpful. 
It is annoying that these subtle differences exist.

I changed my query to use quality rather than 'contains'  as below - and there is no issue when running locally:
az storage account list --query "[?name=='terraformXX'].name" --output tsv

To me, this seems seem like a bug to me in that it does not handle syntax for 'contains'.

Comment: @SuttyHoo Well, but `==` is different from `contains`, simply use Git bash, I think it should be a better way.